# Issue with checking for blank input boxes and sending appropriate message in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm having an issue with my code in VBA properly checking for blank fields and giving the appropriate message in that event and I can't figure out what I've done wrong. My issue is that only the client name blank field checker actually works, the others do nothing at all. Here is a sample of my code.

```
'Error Handling
If (Me!ClientName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Name cannot be blank"
    End

Else
    If IsNumeric(ClientName.Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Client Name must be letters only."
        End
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

If (Me!ClientDoB) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Date of Birth cannot be blank"
    End
End If

If (Me!ClientAdd) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Address cannot be blank"
    End
End If

If (Me!ClientCity) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client City cannot be blank"
    End
Else
    If IsNumeric(ClientCity.Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Client City must be letters only."
        End
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

If (Me!ClientSt) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client State cannot be blank"
    End
End If

If (Me!ClientZC) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Zip Code cannot be blank"
    End
Else
    If IsNumeric(ClientZC.Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "Client Zip Code must be numbers only."
        End
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This only means that only that specific field is empty. Please check if in the other ones some spaces exist. Or Foreground property is white and you cannot see the text...

Comment: What I want to happen is for it to display an error message if the input box is blank and stop the code, but it doesn't do that. the code still completes as though nothing is wrong unless the client name field is blank or numerical.

Comment: Never call `End` for any reason. `Exit Sub` can be useful at times but don't reach for it first. Try to make a logical flow that continues through each procedure without jumping or short circuiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an `if-elseif` structure, such as:

```
If Me.clientname & "" = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Name cannot be blank"
ElseIf Me.clientname Like "*[!A-Za-z]*" Then
    MsgBox "Client Name must contain letters only."
ElseIf Me.clientdob & "" = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Date of Birth cannot be blank"
ElseIf Me.clientadd & "" = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Address cannot be blank"
ElseIf Me.clientcity & "" = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client City cannot be blank"
ElseIf Me.clientcity Like "*[!A-Za-z]*" Then
    MsgBox "Client City must contain letters only."
ElseIf Me.clientst & "" = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client State cannot be blank"
ElseIf Me.clientzc & "" = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Zip Code cannot be blank"
ElseIf Me.clientzc Like "*[!0-9]*" Then
    MsgBox "Client Zip Code must be numbers only."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in MS Access a blank field is not necessarily a NULL. To get around this, use the NZ function instead. It is super helpful in situations like yours in which a field can be blank or NULL (MS Access differentiates between the two!!).

```
If (Nz(Me!ClientAdd,"")) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client Address cannot be blank"
    End
End If
```

This will detect blanks AND nulls and provide you with your expected outcome as you describe. 
The "If Then Else" solution post above is not recommended in your scenario. Because once it finds a "true" scenario all the other scenarios will be ignored...
The code you posted is the correct code (and method) to use. Simply wrap your fields with Nz(!yourfield, Value if Null) function.

Hope this helps.